# Trying to install MongoDB - can't seem to find mongo.so

Tags: ubuntu, php, mongodb

I have mongo installed on the server and running, I can query the command line. PHP and Apache are running fine as well. The problem, however, is that mongo.so isn't in the php lib directory, and I can't find mongo.so to move it there. `sudo find / -name mongo.so` doesn't yield any results. I also can't really find anywhere to download it.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you need the PHP bit to connect to mongo.

You can use PECL to install it by running something like `pecl install mongo`.

You can also install it more manually by going to http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo

I don't believe Ubuntu (at least 10.04) has a PHP-mongo package, at least not according to `aptitude search mongo`.

Update:

As noted below, the OP needed the build-essential package, which will include things like make, gcc, etc.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo

Comment: Turns out I had to install PECL, GCC and MAKE... that was my problem. and `sudo apt-get install PECL` isn't how you do that, apparently!

Comment: Yeah, PECL is just going to download the source for you and compile it. To compile it, you're going to need gcc, make, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this 
http://quadloops.com/how-to-setup-a-php-and-mongodb-development-environment-in-ubuntu-12-04/ guide
to setup PHP and MongoDB developement environment. This one is for Ubuntu, but it think it should work with others too.